# cout the address of a pointer to nonstatic data member is incorrect, why the value is always 1?

Tags: c++

look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class C { public: int a; char b; static int c; };

int C::c = 2;

int main(){
C c;
printf("&C::a = %d, &C::b = %d\n", &C::a, &C::b);
cout << "&C::a = " << &C::a << " &C::b = " << &C::b << endl;

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

the result i get is

&C::a = 0, &C::b = 4

&C::a = 1 &C::b = 1

So why the result of cout is incorrect?

OK, my illustration of this question is ambigious. i am sorry for that. In fact, I want to ask why &C::a and &C::b will cout 1?
As for the result of printf, %d or %p is no matter. They all get the correct result. The difference between them is just %p will output the result in hex format.
And I also know that it's better to add a (void*) conversion in the cout.
After all, thanks for all of you.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour, since `%d` expects an `int` argument but you provide a `int (C::*)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's incorrect"?

Comment: @Jefffrey: No, they're constant expressions and fine.

Comment: @Jefffrey shouldn't matter for location. Allocation != initialization.

Comment: Also for cout, gotta cast to void* (void*)&(C::a). Also any compiler worth  its salt should say "invalid use of non-static data member C::A) then. If someone can explain to me what &C::a actually does I'd greatly appreciate it, in QT creator it says it is of type `int C::*` and it's value is `&C::a`...I would think it should just barf.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams It's a pointer-to-member, much like an offset to `this`. E.g. `struct foo { int a; int b; }; foo f; auto p = &foo::a; (f.*p) = 42; p = &foo::b; (f.*p) = 21;` (oh, and it cannot be portably converted to `void*` IIRC)

Comment: @dyp thanks. Never thought that the same mechanism used for member function could be used for member variables as well. The more you know! That does (interestingly) mean that it can't be port-ably put to cout either.

Comment: I guess the `cout` version is using implicit conversion to bool?

Comment: I have just modify my question illustation. I'm sorry for i didn't illustrate it well. And my question is why the result of &C::a and &C::b are both 1? @MattMcNabb, I ever thought of implicit conversion, but I can't recall any implicit conversion useful in such a situation.